# Cannot manage to change the inner html of a div element

Tags: javascript

I cannot manage to change the inner html of a div element

```
<div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor form-control" data-id="83fa07d0-2bab-4c02-8bb6-a2133ae64bbd"
data-type="input" placeholder="Chat Message" contenteditable="true" id="chatMessageSurrogate"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="Please input a message within 300 
characters." autocomplete="off" style="height: 63px;">wafwafgz</div>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor.form-control").val("Hello!")
document.getElementsByClassName(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor.form-control").innerHTML = "Hello!"
```

but none of them is working

Comment: `val()` is for value use `html()` for `innerHTML`

Comment: Furthermore, `getElementsByClassName` expects a class name (not a class selector) and returns a collection (not a single element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor.form-control").html("Hello!");` should work

Comment: Works great, you just forgot to add a dot before form-control, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

as stated previously .html("hello") should work, but also, getElementsByClassName i believe only works on a single class name and returns and array, so the below should also work

```
$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor.form-control").html("Hello!");
// or
document.getElementsByClassName("emoji-wysiwyg-editor")[0].innerHTML = "Hello!"
```

Comment: What it returns isn't an array, but it is array-like. It's an [`HTMLCollection`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname).

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` accepts a space-separated list of class names.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code there are two different class "emoji-wysiwyg-editor" and "form-control". So you have to use any of one.

```
$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").html("Hello!");

$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor .form-control").html("Hello!");
```

And you want to add html contents in DIV so you have to use html. val is use for input typt.

Comment: This is incorrect. The second selector in your answer will *not* select the element in question, because it is looking for elements with class `form-control` that are descendants of elements with class `emoji-wysiwyg-editor`. There's nothing wrong with the OP's selector (when used with jQuery): `".emoji-wysiwyg-editor.form-control"` selects elements with both classes.

Answer (score 1):

in pure JavaScript with the use of multiple class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("emoji-wysiwyg-editor form-control")[0].innerHTML = "hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JS,

```
var a = document.querySelector('.emoji-wysiwyg-editor');
a.innerHTML = "Hello";
```